Понять поведение алгоритма
Известно несколько рекурсивных алгоритмов генерации синусоиды,
например (на RU Latex не поддерживатся??):
a(n+1) = a(n) + c * b(n),  b(n+1) = b(n) - c * a(n+1)
Дискуссия Статья
И на Python, и на Wolfram эти алгоритмы работают отлично.
Проблема в том, что они мне нужны для digital sound processing.
Я пользуюсь FlowStone. И надо сказать, до сих пор все довольно сложные математические алгоритмы там работали прекрасно, и на Ruby, и на low-level DSP code.
А вот это ведет себя очень странно. Причем все варианты.
Они все сходятся к нулю.
Рано или поздно. При генерации 25 раз в секунду - в течение неск минут.
И!! Даже с добавкой небольшого шума на каждом шаге - также довольно быстро начинают осциллировать возле нуля.
Почти уверен, что это ошибки округления. Но обычно такие ошибки ведут к расходимости. Так ли это, как исправить алгоритм?

Вы на целых пишете или на вещественных?

@StanislavVolodarskiy, На вещественных, float

Тогда код в вопрос добавляйте. Вещественные должны очень-очень медленно деградировать.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, эх, а какой код? На python все нормально. А внутри Flowstone псевдокод, выглядит именно так, как написано.

Код воспроизводящий проблему. Не можете код? Тогда берёте конкретные значения a, b, c, запускаете симуляцию во ФлоуСтоун и помещаете таблицу в вопрос. Таблица должна явно показывать деградацию решения (радиус уходит или что-то ещё). Тогда будет помощь. А пока это вопрос "там работает (я не покажу), тут не работает (вы уж поверьте), разберитесь сами и скорее ответьте". Я бы разобрался, но где я и где ФлоуСтоун?
